# javascript regex to grab particular string in href

Tags: javascript, regex

I am totally new to regex. I need to grab particular set of string in href link dynamically (in this case is 1.867172) that I need to test.

```
<href = 'http://test.stage.cms.9c9media.net:8080/pete-test-1.867172'>
```

Comment: `str.split('-').pop()`

Comment: matching html with a reg exp is a bad idea

Comment: you should better explain what you want to achive

Answer (score 0):

I don't think regex is necessary. A simple split could achieve this.

```js
let URL = "http://test.stage.cms.9c9media.net:8080/pete-test-1.867172"
let testID = URL.split('-')[2]
console.log(testID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the next regular expression with a [capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) for all the characters following the last `-` char:

```
regular expression: /.*-(.*)/
```

Combine the previous regular expression with [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get what you looking for:

```js
let link = document.getElementById("myLink");
let url = link.attributes.href.value;
let pattern = url.match(/.*-(.*)/)[1];
console.log("pattern: " + pattern);
```

```html
<a id="myLink" href='http://test.stage.cms.9c9media.net:8080/pete-test-1.867172'></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number you want is always between a dash and the closing '

https://regexr.com/48s6u

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regex solution. Please note this will capture any part of string of format `<number>.<number>`

```js
var source = "http://test.stage.cms.9c9media.net:8080/pete-test-1.867172"
var regex = /\d\.\d+/;
var matches = source.match(regex);
if(matches)
  console.log(matches[0])
```